# Mysql - Is a SELECT inside of a SELECT an efficeint query

Tags: mysql

I have a table which holds data from a periodic scan of events occurring a number of servers where each event will have an integer count of the event at each scan time.

I want to extract the daily maximum event_count for a specific event on each server for a date range.

I am using the query

```
SELECT server,event_code,event_date,event_count 
FROM (select inside.* FROM event_scan AS inside 
    WHERE
        (inside.event_code='code1' OR inside.event_code='85730ACD_2012_0F')
    AND inside.event_date > '2016-12-31'
    AND inside.event_date < '2017-08-31' 
    ORDER by inside.server,inside.event_date asc,inside.event_code,inside.event_count desc)
as outside group by server,event_date,event_code;
```

Table details outlined below

mysql> show columns in event_scan;

```
| Field       | Type        |

| server      | varchar(80) |

| event_code  | varchar(80) |

| scan_date   | date        |

| scan_time   | time        |

| event_count | int(11)     |
```

+---------------------------------------------+

mysql> select count(*) from event_scan;

```
+-----------+

| count(*)  |

+-----------+

| 380684359 |

+-----------+
```

Comment: Can you give an indication of what the tables are, perhaps even 1 line of data?

The term "efficient" is subjective, based on the data/structure you are reading

Comment: Questions about SQL performance should include `SHOW CREATE TABLE event_scan` so we can see indexes.. and the output from EXPLAIN [query]

Comment: Here is the first row of the table

mysql> select * from event_scan limit 1;

+------- -+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+

| server  | event_code | scan_date  | scan_time | event_count    |

+---------+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+

| VEPRD01 | Abz412     | 2011-01-31 | 19:30:00  |              0 |

+---------+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+

Comment: The inner subquery might be ignored by the optimiser. No way of knowi g what is happening without an explain plan.  Please add (as fomattwd text) the explain outpur for you query. Also suggest you provide full ddl of table including all indexes.